# run yocto package via systemd service in image

Tags: linux, yocto, systemd, bitbake, recipe

I have an yocto image with my own package appended. My recipe:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_append := ":${THISDIR}/../systemd/files"
inherit systemd
SRC_URI = "file://myserver.tar.gz"

SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE = "enable"
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "serverAutoStart.service"

SRC_URI_append = " file://serverAutoStart.service"

FILES_${PN} += "${systemd_unitdir}/system/serverAutoStart.service"


do_compile() {
        make
}

#for myserver package
do_install() {
        install -m 0755 -d ${D}${bindir} ${D}${docdir}/myserver
        install -m 0644 ${S}//myserver ${D}${bindir}
}

#for systemd package
do_install_append() {
  install -d ${D}/${systemd_unitdir}/system
  install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/serverAutoStart.service ${D}/${systemd_unitdir}/system
}
```

In this recipe I have a systemd class inherited. I also have a systemd service which I need to auto execute package `myserver` when some machine is ON. Where is located this package and how can I execute it from systemd unit?(What `path in ExecStart` I need to use).

Thanks for your answers! May be you give me some remarks, because I`m relatively new in this area

Comment: Can you rephrase your question and make it clearer? I'm unsure what you're asking about.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk I just want to run binary file `myserver` from systemd unit and I don`t know where is this package(myserver) located in my image.
The point is I will flash some device with my custom image and I need to execute yocto package when this device is ON

Comment: did you add the package to the image? `IMAGE_INSTALL`

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk, thanks for reply.  Yes, and I have my `server` package in tmp/deploy/images/<manifest file>. But where will be the binary itself when I flash device with this image? May be there is some thing I missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that to use systemd service you need to make sure that `systemd` in `DISTRO_FEATURES`.

check with:

```
bitbake -e (YOUR_IMAGE) | grep ^DISTRO_FEATURES=
```

Because `sysvinit` is the default init manager, make sure that:

```
INIT_MANAGER = "systemd"
```

Here is a simple `systemd` recipe example (`meta-custom/recipes-example/systemd-example/`):

- **files/example.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Systemd Service Example
Before=basic.target

[Service]
Type=simple

# Put the path to the binary installed by do_install()
ExecStart=/usr/bin/example
ExecStop=/bin/killall example
ExecReload=/bin/killall example; /usr/bin/example

# These are optional, you can remove them, or
# read about systemd properties for more control
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30s

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

- **files/example.c**
- **systemd-example_0.1.bb**

```
SUMMARY = "Systemd example recipe"
DESCRIPTION = "Systemd service example for xxx"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://example.c"
SRC_URI += "file://example.service"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile(){
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} ${WORKDIR}/example.c -o ${WORKDIR}/example
}

do_install(){
    install -d ${D}/usr/bin

    # Install the binary
    install -m 0744 ${WORKDIR}/example ${D}/usr/bin

    # Install systemd stuff
    install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/systemd
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/example.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/systemd
}

# Systemd class stuff
inherit systemd
NATIVE_SYSTEMD_SUPPORT = "1"
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "example.service"
```

No need for `SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE = "enable"` because it is enable by default.

**UPDATE**

Now, add the recipe to your image via:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " systemd-example"
```

put that line in your custom image recipe or in `local.conf` for testing.

When you build the image you will find `/usr/sbin/example` and it will be automatically executed by the systemd service `example.service`, to check for the status :

```
systemctl status example
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Did I understand correctly: when I will build my custom image and flash device with this image, my binary file(example) will be located in usr/bin directory of this device?

Comment: Check my UPDATE in the answer

Comment: Thank you a lot! You really helped me figure out many things when writing a custom recipe.

Comment: Hello @BelHadjSalemTALEL @Oleksandr, I am trying to do the same thing with my STM32MP1 based Avenger96 board. But when I run `systemctl status example` I get the `error -sh: systemctl: command not found`. My image recipe is similar to above recipe. And doing `bitbake -e (YOUR_IMAGE) | grep ^DISTRO_FEATURES=` shows `systemd`. But my `INIT_MANAGER = "none"`. How to change it to `systemd`? Can you please let me know how to resolve this issue and where will be these service files present in rootfs? My build system is Docker for Windows with Ubuntu 20.04 and Yocto.

Comment: @Preeti , just set `INIT_MANAGER = "systemd"` in `local.conf` or your custom distro.